# Vue.js : removing item from list after added a new item caused a bug

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<li v-for="(l, i) of lineList" :key="l._id"> 

data () {
        return {
            lineList: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
         query() {
            axios.get(domain + 'line')
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.lineList = res.data.data;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                    });
        },
        add() {
            axios.post(domain + 'line', {line: '432432'})
                    .then(res => {
                        this.lineList.unshift(res.data.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        },
        remove(line, i) {
            axios.delete(domain + 'line/' + line._id)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.lineList.splice(i, 1);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        }
    },
```

Above is the code snippets from my project.I am using newest version of vue.js 2.

My Problem is that when I try to do this.remove() after this.add(),wrong item deleted,I readlly dont know why,someone have any idea please tell me, thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are getting, can you show tour html code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would try the following:

```
remove(line) {
    axios.delete(domain + 'line/' + line._id)
    .then(res => {
        let index = this.lineList.indexOf(line)
        this.lineList.splice(index, 1);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

With this, you are sure that you have the correct index for the item at the moment that you want to delete it thanks to `let index = this.lineList.indexOf(line)`

Comment: Thanks, its a good advice,I dont know exactly what reason caused my weird bug,but after I taken your advice,the bug gone.